# Android/Java: How to remove the filetype extention from a URI?

Tags: android, uri, substring, ringtone

So I am working with URIs in Android to set ringtones for individual contacts. Problem is, the way the ringtone selector works is that it doesn't like something such as `myringtone.mp3`. Instead, it just wants `myringtone`. Weird, but I guess that's just how it goes. So I have a URI like `file:///sdcard/tag/ringtones/ringtone.mp3`. How would I get the URI to remove the extension so the ringtone manager uses it properly? The way ringtones are set are with this line:

```
values.put(ContactsContract.Contacts.CUSTOM_RINGTONE, uri.toString());
```

So the URI is in string form. Using substrings I should be able to do it, but I don't know how I'd write a method to remove the final 4 characters in a string. Can anyone give me some advice here?

Thanks!

Comment: Forgive me if you have, but you should at least *try* to solve it before asking. Post the code you've produced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried?...

```
uri.toString().substring(0, uri.toString().length() - 4);
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be minus 4? .mp3 has a char length of 4, but to be honest I don't really know how substrings work.

Comment: @JMRboosties: My bad - I always forget the Java syntax for substring(int start, int end) suggests 'absolute' end rather than the length.

Answer (score 5):

For situations where you don't know what the extension may be or unknown length, try:

```
uri.toString().substring(0, uri.getString().lastIndexOf("."));
```